# Is there a way to add a Material UI Menu component to the las column of DataGrid component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using the DataGrid compnent of Material UI to render some information. I'd like to render a Menu in the last column of each row to take some actions over that specific row, for example navigate to a new route.

I've managed to add a field to the last column but for some reason the Menu wont open and i think it has to do with the state management of the open prop for Menu.

Here is the code

```
const getNewCells = () => {
const newCols = columns;

newCols.push({
  field: ' ',
  type: 'number',
  flex: 1,
  renderCell: (cell) => {
    return (
      <>
        <Box
          aria-controls="simple-menu-1"
          aria-haspopup="true"
          onClick={() => setMenuOpen(true)}
          size="small"
          component={Button}
          width="2rem!important"
          height="2rem!important"
          minWidth="2rem!important"
          minHeight="2rem!important"
        >
          <Box
            component={MoreVert}
            width="1.25rem!important"
            height="1.25rem!important"
            position="relative"
            top="2px"
            color={theme.palette.gray[500]}
          />
        </Box>
        <Menu
          id="simple-menu-1"
          open={menuOpen}
          onClose={() => setMenuOpen(false)}
          anchorOrigin={{
            vertical: 'bottom',
            horizontal: 'center',
          }}
          transformOrigin={{
            vertical: 'top',
            horizontal: 'center',
          }}
        >
          <MenuItem onClick={() => goToDetail(cell.id)}>Detail</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem onClick={() => {}}>Transition to Something</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem onClick={() => {}}>Delete</MenuItem>
        </Menu>
      </>
    );
  },
});
return newCols;
};
```

Comment: I am also not able to do so. Did you get any solution? @Nicolas

Comment: It is easy to do this in mui v5, but in v4 it is tricky. I have found a solution and will update soon.

Answer (score 1):

İ would go with putting `MoreVertIcon` from `mui-icons` on the last column.Then, `onClick` action access `params.row`